# Java Maven Library Project Template

Tags: java, maven

I would like to create a library (artifact) that I can host on maven central or install locally using maven.

Is there any example project template that I can use for this? How should a project be structured? I searched for a while but could not find any examples that can lead me to a solution.

Any ideas and tips are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am more interested in the project structure

Comment: I don't know the procedure to be deployed on maven central. But your library just has to be a maven project to be eligible to be deployed on any internal repository (artifactory, nexus, etc.)

Comment: Please checkout https://dzone.com/articles/publish-your-artifacts-to-maven-central

Comment: How should the project be structured though besides the procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you do not deploy a *project* to MavenCentral, but artifacts. So your internal project structure does not matter much.

Nevertheless, it is advisable to follow Maven standards. Put the java source code into `src/main/java`, the tests into `src/test/java` etc. You can use the quickstart archetype to generate a project.